# Differentiable structure on the boundary induces differentiable structure on the entire manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

I am trying to prove the uniqueness of smoothed corners, in detail.
In Milnor's notes, [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/homsph.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/homsph.pdf),
there's an explanation in p.34-37 on how to do it.

The guiding question is: Given two manifolds with boundary $W_1, W_2$, can we put a smooth structure on $W = W_1\times W_2$ so that $W_1\times W_2-\partial W_1\times\partial W_2$, $\partial W_1\times W_2$, and $W_1\times\partial W_2$ are smoothly embedded submanifolds? **And if there is, is it unique?**

Milnor shows there is at least one. He also uses his Lemma 8.2 $(\dagger)$ to assert that all possible structures will induce in the boundary $\partial W$ identical structures up to diffeomorphism. This is because $\partial W$ is equal to $\partial W_1\times W_2\cup W_1\times\partial W_2$ and the differentiable structures of both are fixed so the lemma applies.

Notice he didn't show all possible structures on $W$ are identical up to diffeomorphism. He only says the induced smooth structures on $\partial W$ will be identical up to diffeomorphism.

**My question is:** though he didn't say it, is it true that all possible structures on $W$ are equivalent as well?

$(\dagger)$ The Lemma 8.2 says that when gluing two smooth manifolds along their diffeomorphic boundaries, the smooth structures on the end manifold (compatible with the first two) are equivalent up to diffeomorphism.

**What I have done:** One can immediately see that this smooth structure in $\partial W$ has to extend to a collar, so there is an inclusion $\partial W\times [0,\infty)\subseteq W$ which is a smooth embeddeding, with $\partial W\times [0,\infty)$ given the product smooth structure, with the standard one in $[0,\infty)$.

The hope is that by connectedness we can claim that the differentiable structure on $W$ is uniquely determined, once we have the one in the collar.

Comment: No, in general, the smooth structure on the boundary does not uniquely determine the smooth structure on the manifold. I am not sure if this is what you wanted to know. Or, maybe your question is: Suppose that we have a smooth manifold $M$ with boundary. Do the smooth structures on the interior and on the boundary uniquely determine the smooth structure on $M$?

Comment: I think your first sentence is very promising! But I need to clarify: I am already assuming that the fixed smooth structure on the boundary is extendable to the entire manifold. The question is whether it could be extended in non-equivalent ways.

Comment: In particular, this would imply that the smooth structure on the product $W_1\times W_2$ is not unique, even though we enforce that $W_1\times\partial W_2, \partial W_1\times W_2, W_1\times W_2-\partial W_1\times \partial W_2$ are smoothly embedded.

Comment: These are really different questions, I suggest you think through which one you are really asking.

Comment: The first implies the second, using the results of Milnor's Appendix. So I am asking about the first.

Comment: But the first has negative answer, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question to the best of my understanding of it.

1. Your first question is: Suppose that $W$ is a topological manifold with boundary whose boundary is smoothable and extends to a smooth structure on $W$. Is this extension unique up to diffeomorphism?

The answer to this question is negative. For instance, take a closed  4-dimensional manifold $M$ which admits two nonequilavent smooth structures $s_1, s_2$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $s_1, s_2$ agree on an open nonempty subset $U\subset M$. Let $W$ be obtained by removing from it the interior of smooth ball contained in $U$. Then restricting $s_1, s_2$ to $W$ we obtain two smooth structures on it (I retain the notation $s_1, s_2$ for these). If they were equivalent, there would be a diffeomorphism
$$
f: (W,s_1)\to (W,s_2). 
$$
But each diffeomorphism $S^3\to S^3$ is smoothly extends to the 4-ball $B^4$. Then we would obtain a diffeomorphism $(M,s_1)\to (M,s_2)$, which is a contradiction.

2. Your second question appears to be: Suppose that in the setting of Question 1, we have two extensions $s_1, s_2$ of the given smooth structure on $\partial W$ to $W$. Suppose, in addition, that
   $$
   (int(W), s_1), (int(W), s_2)
   $$
   are diffeomorphic. Doe it follow that $(W,s_1), (W,s_2)$ are diffeomorphic?

This is a harder question which also has negative answer. See Benoit's answer to an MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81714/uniqueness-of-compactification-of-an-end-of-a-manifold).

Comment: Thank you for this terrific answer! I think the second question, however, has an extra assumption: namely, I am assuming $(int(W), s_1), (int(W), s_2)$ are diffeomorphic via the identity map (this is because int(W) is inheriting the same structure from $W_1\times W_2-\partial W_1\times\partial W_2\hookrightarrow W_1\times W_2$). But maybe this still has a negative answer. I've been trying to understand Benoit's answer on this, but it seems he is only dealing with the case without this assumption.

Comment: I see what you mean. Let me think about it.